# How to return Case when Contact picklist field is selected

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, customer-portal

I have a use case and need help choosing the best method to solve it.

User license: Customer Community.
User profile: Customer Portal.

1. When Sys admin sets a picklist value on the Contact obj to Primary, user should see all Cases with the Account name ABC in the Customer Portal.
2. When Sys admin sets a picklist value on the Contact obj to Secondary, user should only see Cases they own.

I know I can do this by writing Apex but how can it be done declaratively?

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuilt the logic of Apex in flow which is declarative option. Please refer this link as a starting point:
https://automationchampion.com/2021/09/30/creating-custom-record-sharing-logic-using-salesforce-flow/